# Обработка абзацев

Tags: php

Есть текст в нем будет 5-6 абзацев, как вставить после каждого абзаца <p></p> некий текст ?

Comment: просто сделать замену `</p` на `некий текст </p>` не подходит?

Answer (score 1):

классы и тексты подставляйте свои

```
$('.content > p').each(function() {
    $(this).after('текст');
});
```

**UPD:**

**PHP:**

```
$str = "<p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p><p>4</p><p>5</p><p>6</p>";
$text = 'некий текст';

$str = str_replace('</p>', '</p>'.$text, $str);

echo $str;
```

Comment: это php? мне кажется, это javascript.

Comment: @KoVadim, не заметил метки php

Answer (score 1):

Можно с помощью css

```
p:after {content: "текст"}
```

Comment: Прочитайте внимательно метку к вопросу и предыдущий ответ.